# What is the meaning of 'No bundle URL present' in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native

When I run a react-native project, I get a error `no bundle URL present`, but I don't know what mistakes I do, I was very confused.

[image: no bundle url present error]

Comment: I faced this problem in react native iOS app. Just open the xcodeproj in ios folder in xcode and run it from there. Make sure you are not on proxy.

Comment: Most of the time, clearing the build directory helps me `rm -rf ios/build/`

Comment: That helps me in most of situations. But in this particular case I was able to fix this error by this command (react-native: "0.60.4"):
`watchman watch-del-all`

Comment: It usually means that your metro bundler is not running, some people run that in their own terminals or on the standard computer terminal. I usually close the terminal, restart the app and that fixes it.

Comment: For me it happened after releasing to the App Store. I had to undo the steps described in the [Publishing to Apple AppStore](https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store#1-enable-app-transport-security) page

Comment: For me, the issue was that the computer I was running this on had internet access via the iPhone's USB cable (shared hotspot over USB). Switching to the device's shared Wifi hotspot solved it.

It looks like when sharing internet via USB from iOS, localhost may not be available.

Answer (score 161):

Solve the error `No bundle URL present` by:

- Running the following command in your project root directory to delete the iOS build directory, and to kill other React Native sessions (assuming they're running on default port 8081) before re-building:

`rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios`

- Update your React Native workflow to avoid these error occur by combining the above combination of commands into an alias and appending it to your Bash config file .bashrc with this command:

`echo "alias rni=\"kill \$(lsof -t -i:8081); rm -rf ios/build/; react-native run-ios\"" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc`

Now you can run React Native iOS build (without worrying about some of the common red error screens of death appearing) with a simple alias shortcut:

`rni`

Comment: Very useful for me.  The only other thing I had to do was to quit the simulator if not already closed.

Comment: glad this is on page 2 500 answers down

Comment: I have to remove the `build` folder and it works. Kudos !

Comment: it returns `kill: not enough arguments` for me :( anybody know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 90):

I just ran into this problem as well (first time getting started with React Native).  The problem disappeared when - while an ios simulation(`react-native run-ios`) was running - I ran `npm install` and then `react-native run-ios` again.  In the terminal window, it showed that it was bundling, and then the simulator showed the welcome screen.

[Check this link for briefs](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial) after `react-native init PropertyFinder` line try to use `npm start` (This one works for me)

========================================================================

**UPDATE for 16.9**

My port 8081 was blocked by McAfee. Using a different port directly wasn't working `react-native start --port=8082` and `react-native run-ios --port=8082`

Tried almost all solutions given here. but anything didn't work.

```
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.5",
```

**Solution:**

Searched for 8081 in Xcode and replaced all of them with 8082. Then run the same commands to build and run the app. App works smoothly

```
react-native start --port=8082
react-native run-ios --port=8082
```

[image]

Comment: @dcp Have you tried running "react-native run-ios" multiple times while it is already booted up?  It seems like every time I spin my app up I need to do it at least twice (waiting about 2 minutes between each time).

Comment: works for me, but would love to find a long-term fix that didn't involve this step each time.

Comment: `react-native run-ios --port=8082` worked for me!

Answer (score 88):

This problem happens when you not allow unsecure connections via localhost, or maybe you tried to accept unsecure connections via http.

To fix this, add this on `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: What a hero this guy is. Saved me and my macbook from jumping out the window! I had changed my exception domain from `localhost` to my local network address in Info.plist and hence it was not resolving. I added a block for 'localhost' as an exception domain and it worked.

Comment: Seriously your answer came in like god to me.... brother you rock ..... I have no words. thanks you, I stuck in it from Thursday.

Comment: `<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
   <key>localhost</key>
   <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
   </dict>
  </dict>` worked for me but same idea

Comment: Thanks, a great reminder that saved my day. However to address the No bundle URL present problem we only need the NSExceptionDomains for localhost as mentioned by the previous comment. No need to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true as it turns off ATS completely and you'll need to give Apple a good reason when uploading to the App Store.

Comment: You're the super hero

Answer (score 53):

Had same problem when I did bundle my app.
Check that your `main.jsbundle` is targeted to your main Project

[image]

Comment: This somehow happened to me as part of my react-native 0.60 upgrade.

Comment: video link for the same, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCs2GsWNkoo

Comment: this happened to me as well.  but then i clicked on it.  but still same issue

Comment: I am so glad I found your comment, thank you, this was exactly my problem.

Comment: it works for me, but the error repeated for the fresh react native project. Have you found a permanent solution?

Answer (score 37):

As instructed in the error message:

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run "sudo xcodebuild -license" and then retry this command.

Running the following command worked:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Comment: tks this is work for me after run in terminal and build in xcode after

Comment: Nope. Still din't work for me. I am running in a different port , 8081 is blocked

Comment: I had a MacOS Update before and as app wasn't running after the update with above error message. This solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 35):

Reason:

This is because the app cannot find out the server (which serves the UI - by javascript code).

Solution:

- Make sure everything related to react native closed (not necessary, just to have clean start for my solution, after my explanation, you can figure out this is needed or not)
- run `npm run start` or `yarn start` first
- wait for this command done job (usually you will see `Loading dependency graph, done.`)
- run `react-native run-ios/android`

Explanation:

- React Native comes with 2 parts:

  - Native part
  - Javascript part
- Build commands:

  - `react-native run-ios/android` is to build native part then deploy to devices and start app on devices (simulator/emulator/real device). This usually took 3~4 mins to finish.
  - `npm run start` or `yarn start` is to build the javascript part and start the dev server to serve the built UI to the app. This usually took 30 secs to finish.

=> Normally, the javascript part finished first then the native part came later. (based on time they used).

=> this is only true for the first time build (fresh build).

=> for re-build:

- The native part just took 10~15 secs to check changes and because no change for native part => done before the javascript part was built and served. (I am not sure the javascript part was rebuilt or not but it took long time than native part)
- So that is why we had this issue, the app ran and required thing that did not exist yet.

Bonus:

- `react-native run-ios/android` will auto start the dev server for you.
- That's why when you ran `react-native run-ios/android` right after `react-native init <app_name>`, everything ran well. (because auto start feature and the time was took for fresh build as state above).
- Other "removing" solutions worked because they forced rebuilding.

Time used on this answer was relative to my machine => may different on others.

Answer (score 28):

Close your simulator and the terminal. Open new one and go to your project, then upgrade your react-native like this:

```
react-native upgrade
```

Issue in: [Infinite recursion in RCTFatal when the bundle fails to execute](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5090).

Comment: yes, but in my case I didn't need to upgrade. Closing terminal and simulator was enough for me.

Comment: @gianni What version of react-native are you running now?

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference, still seeing the error.

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to close the simulator as well and then run react-native run-ios

Comment: Didn't help
```
info No version passed. Fetching latest...
warn Specified version "0.61.5" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.61.5" semver range. No need to upgrad
```

Answer (score 21):

following these steps:

- open ios file project with xcode
- in project bundle delete main.jsbundle file
- add new empty file by main.jsbundle name
- Run comment: react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
- now react-native run-ios

youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCs2GsWNkoo

Comment: It worked for me. However, local images aren't showing on iOS simulator. Any idea?

Comment: if you're running ios 14 on a react <0.62 you'll need to patch

Comment: It worked for me but the images is broken now, i get no images... on my iPhone device, HELP?

Comment: but, i have a little question, why there is no `main.jsbundle` shown on my `vscode` or `terminal` ? what is it ?

now there are 3 changes are in `project.pbxproj` file about main.jsbundle file 

what is going on here? what are these files and what was the problem?

Answer (score 16):

Try running this code:

`$ sudo xcodebuild -license`

This may fix the issue. This works for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error and was able to run the app only through Xcode. `react-native run-ios` did not work. To resolve the issue you need to remove the `build` folder at `YOUR_PROJECT/ios/build/`. After this you should be able to run your app through `react-native run-ios` again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

For me the issue was it couldn't create the JS bundle. It doesn't state the error when building from Xcode so there is no way for you to know this. To find the error run the following command.

`react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ./ios/release/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios/release/main.jsbundle`

For me the error was something with missing PureRenderMixin component. To which the solution can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13078. Basicly you have to manually install react@16.0.0-alpha.3. This can be done via running this command.

`npm i --save react@16.0.0-alpha.3`

This issue is now happening for everybody because newer versions of react alphas are being released (particularly alpha.5) and they are breaking react-native builds.

Comment: the command 'react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ./ios/release/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios/release/main.jsbundle' will describe any error in building the bundle. until this command is succesfull, run-ios won't work

Comment: my current error is that the '@connect' of 'react-redux' is not somehow recognized?

Comment: Maybe try adding `"plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]` to your .babelrc file. Or try it with the connect HOC.

Comment: @urbancvek, for me the error is this `The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement` and its referencing `@babel` library inside of `node_modules`, I have found nothing that has addressed this.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the cases this problem occurs when the DNS lookup / IP lookup fails to find localhost.

**Solution :**

Try adding the localhost ip to your etc host file.

you can add the below lines to your etc host file (/etc/hosts)

127.0.0.1     localhost

255.255.255.255   broadcasthost

::1 l . ocalhost

**To confirm this is the issue**
you can hit the bundle url on safari (if you try it in chrome this will resolve but safari won't be able to resolve it). http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false

Comment: After migrating to a brand new computer, this was what I needed.  TY!

Comment: Yep same here on a new computer!

Comment: My problem was setting proxy on my network configuration, I just remove proxy and it works well.

Comment: It should be `http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false` now

Answer (score 11):

Be sure that your ATS settings are correct in .plist file.

You can find the file at **/ios/{{project_name}}/Info.plist**

localhost must be defined as exception request target like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

*(dont forget to remove this on release version..)

Answer (score 10):

Solution --> 
`npm start` then open new Terminal and go to your project path and then hit
`react-native run-ios` it works for me

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue. But my problem was my Mac and iPhone were not in same wifi network.

So ensure that they are all in same network and rebuild once again. If this is not the case, try the solutions mentioned by other members here.

Comment: This was the problem for me. It should be the first place you check.

Comment: You're a hero! No clue why I didn't check it at the first place

Comment: For me, WLAN was not activated on the iPhone. Once I activated it, the problem went away.

Answer (score 10):

I had to run "react-native start" in a separate terminal. For some reason it wasn't running

`Edit`: Also, it turns out this was necessary because of a file permission not getting set properly. I am able to fix it by running the following command in an affected project directory.

`chmod 777 node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command`

Answer (score 9):

What solved it for me:

- Open a terminal window
- `cd` into `YOUR_PROJECT/ios`
- Remove the build folder with `rm -r build`
- Run `react-native run-ios` again

Alternatively, you could open Finder, navigate to `YOUR_PROJECT/ios` and delete the `build` folder.

Then run `react-native run-ios` again.

Source: [Andrew Bancroft](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/04/22/solving-react-natives-no-bundle-url-present-error/)

Answer (score 8):

Just run in Terminal `react-native start`:

```
cd your react native app directory/ react-native start
```

It will start up the packager, now don't close this terminal window, in another terminal window run your project. This is the only want that I found to get it working properly.

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue with react-native v0.42.1. Try to close all terminal and XCode instances and run:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
watchman version
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: "This is an issue with react-native v0.42.1. " - It exists with v.0.43 as well.

Answer (score 5):

check your network proxy , better shut it down.

or u should  find an other way to maintain the packager server

Comment: Thanks, I opened the global VPN to cross the Great Fire Wall!

Comment: I disabled the automatic proxy configuration in Mac. It worked after 2 days efforts :D...Thanks.

Comment: I was indeed running a VPN that I didn't even remember. shutting it down worked!

Answer (score 5):

first close the simulator, then run these on terminal

```
npm install

react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried all solutions above, didn't work for me. This is what worked for me, you can try this out if the answers above didn't work out for you.

1. Open your project workspace on Xcode, and delete `main.jsbundle` file in [PROJECT-NAME]/main.jsbundle
2. Create a new main.jsbundle, in that same folder. {right-click -> choose new file -> it'll open a dialog box, look for `Others` section, -> choose `Empty` -> name the file `main.jsbundle` -> save
3. Then go back to the terminal of your project. And run this command:

`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

4. Start your packager and run the IOS app again

I do hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 5):

I am running iOS simulator and this method works:

**1. Clean your native project**

1.a For Android project

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

1.b For iOS project

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

**2. Clean your reactnative cach**

2.a If you are using npm

```
  npm start -- --reset-cache
```

2.b If you are using yarn

```
  yarn cache clean
```

After that you can run your project again.

Comment: What worked for me is simply using `npm start` and that alone suffice! Starting metro packager first! in a window make it works! No need for --reset-cache too!

None of the other elements mattered!

Answer (score 5):

In my case I have accidentally deleted this script from the Build Phases in Xcode.

So, Make sure to have this script. If not, just click on " + "  & select "New Run Script Phase" then paste the following code.

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was fixed by restarting the `adb` server: `adb kill-server && adb start-server`

Answer (score 4):

check your 'localhost' key at NSExceptionDomains dict in info.plist

if it doesn't exist, it causes error.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the easiest/quickest way to bypass this is to exit the app within the simulator (2 x `Cmd + Shift + H`) and re-launch.

Answer (score 3):

It has happened to me as well, after restarting my mac. There's a launchPackager terminal window opening up when you run your app on the simulator. I closed that window and terminated the process (I also cloosed the simulator), then run again react-native run-ios and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue happen for me as well...the issue was the packer wasn't running it seemed probably because my default shell was zsh.  react-native tires to open a new terminal window and run `.../node_modules/react-native/packager/launchPackager.command` but this didn't run.  Manually running that (and keeping it running) fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using `nvm` and multiple versions of node installed, here is the solution:

1. Say that you run `npm install -g react-native-cli` in `node v6.9.5`.
2. Now make `node v6.9.5` as default by running `nvm alias default 6.9.5`
3. Now run `react-native run-ios`

The problem is, you have multiple versions of node installed via `nvm` and to install `react-native-cli` you have switched or installed latest version of node, which is not marked as default node to point in `nvm` yet. When you run `react-native run-ios` this opens up another new terminal window in which default `nvm` is not pointed to the node version where you have installed `react-native-cli`. Just follow the above setup, I hope that should help.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried all solutions below, but nothing work:

- `sudo xcodebuild -license` or
- Remove the build folder with `rm -r build` and run `react-native run-ios` or
- `npm start` and run `react-native run-ios`
- Add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to localhost

I solved by do this:

- Open host file `sudo vi /private/etc/hosts` (if you use VSCode, use this `sudo code /private/etc/hosts`)
- Add three line if it's not exist

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 localhost
::1 localhost
```

- Run `react-native run-ios` again.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out my hosts file was incompatible (too big or incorrect) for RN. I was using it as an ad-blocker.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have .jsbundle in your your project

Add

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

in your react native code
try to reopen the project

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
Open the .xcodeworkspace project in your xcode by navigating it via "Terminal",
"open /ios/.xcodeworkspace" Hit Enter.

Step 2:
Delete the main.jsbundle file inside the  folder you have

Step 3:
Go back to VS Code, type this,
`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

This generate you the new main.jsbundle file.

Step 4:
react-native run-ios

you wont see the error again

Answer (score 2):

To me, the problem was that the Wi-Fi was turned off on my device, so it couldn't connect to the Metro server.

Comment: Ended up being my exact issue, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with `RN 0.49.5`. 
I've tried lots of methods, but no one works. Finally i worked this out.
It's simple and easy.

Main idea is to change the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, but it's not where the RN tells you. It's in **RCTBundleURLProvider.m#- (BOOL)isPackagerRunning:(NSString *)host**.

Changes of code:
`oc
- NSString *host = ipGuess ?: @"localhost";
+ NSString *host = ipGuess ?: @"127.0.0.1";`

This is ok for simulator. If it's device, just change the ip address to your machine's.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 1):

another thing that working for me , is to open the project in xcode, and then clean and build it. usually it reruns the packaging server and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window

```
cd into YOUR_PROJECT/ios
```

Remove the build folder with `rm -r build`

After that open your project in Xcode and run once. it will run with starting the server and create the `main.jsbundle` file.

Now if you Run `react-native run-ios` from terminal again it will work as expected.

Hope it will help!.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the below command:

```
killall -9 node
rm -rf ios/build
react-native run-ios
```

it will open launchpackager.command and the application will install on the ios simulator

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred to me because Metro bundler started and received focus while I was typing on my keyboard in another window. My accidental input in the newly opened terminal window caused Metro bundler to crash. Rerunning `react-native run-ios` and **waiting patiently** fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For Mcafee Macbook users :

sudo launchctl remove com.mcafee.agent.macmn

Answer (score 1):

Turn off/on **wi-fi** on device / on mac, rebuild app

For deeper debug: See XCode log, it may contain: "Could not connect to the server" with exact URL.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the terminal throws absolutely no errors and the issue was the vpn connection of my mac so I had to disconnect the vpn and the problem got resolved .

Answer (score 1):

here is simple solution, i tired above almost all solution but no benefit:

For simulator:-

1. go to xcode.
2. create a file main.jsbundle (if already please delete).
3. run a command into terminal :--

npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

4. now run your project

now will worked properly in simulataor.

For Real device:-

1. pick that main.jsbundle  file from vscode and drop it to xcode below project name.
2. now goto build phase and go to compile sources.
3. click on + and search main.jsbundle and add it.

now run your project again will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `launchPackage.command` are running in a terminal and try run again. It will build the bundle. It is kinda like webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your hosts that `127.0.0.1    localhost` is not delete
2. check that the network agent is not set up
3. then `npm install` & `react-native upgrade` to reset your project

Answer (score 0):

It's because your client cannot reach your packager server.

If you are a Chinese Coder just as I am, I think you might using VPN get through the GFW. When your VPN tool is in 'Global Mode', all your request will travel through the world and cannot get localhost

Try 'Auto Proxy Mode'.

If you are not come from China, or your VPN setting is already 'Auto Proxy Mode', I suggest you shut down your packager server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

...another reason why this is happening is if you have installed Visual Studio Code [React Native Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsmobile.vscode-react-native) but you keep trying to use react native in the terminal: it will work the first time but then it will stop and show you the red no bundle screen.

launching react native from vscode works perfectly instead...

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, i had to remove node_modules directory and run npm install.

```
$ rm -rf node_modules   (make sure you're in the ios project directory)
$ npm install
```

If you get error "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib", do the following:

```
$ brew uninstall --force node --ignore-dependencies node
$ brew uninstall icu4c --ignore-dependencies icu4c
$ brew install icu4c
$ brew unlink icu4c && brew link icu4c --force
$ brew install node

$ npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: duplicate answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471978/728287

Comment: U think that if a saw his answer right here, I would took the pain to write it again ? xD @GianfrancoP.

Answer (score 0):

`export FORCE_BUNDLING=true` worked for me. There was a warning in the console that it was not getting bundled.

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to the network by cable and wifi on my macbook, disabled wifi and just hit run and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

We got around this by removing the SKIP_BUNDLING option in the build script that the RN docs suggested adding to speed up the debug build.  The real fix (for our cause) is included in RN 0.57:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20553

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

- Open a terminal window
- cd into YOUR_PROJECT/ios
- Remove the **build** folder with rm -r build
- Run react-native run-ios again

Answer (score 0):

This problem may happen when we have multiple versions of node managed by nvm and default version is not intended version to run react-native. (make sure it is Node 8.3 or newer)

> react-native run-ios

opens a new terminal and runs the version of node found in the $PATH.

If it finds an older version of node not supported by react native, it may give this error.

Make sure, the $PATH variable is already pointing to intended version of node(make sure it is Node 8.3 or newer) when a new terminal is opened.

That solved the issue for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off global proxy (shadowsocks)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you probably have close the Metro Bundler Window or it might be crashed. just open another terminal/cmd in the project directory and run `npm start`. By Running `npm start` React Native will launch the MetroBundler Window once again. After bundler finishes the `BUNDLE` process, just reload the Application and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that may sound weird but none of those answers worked for me.
I'm now at react-native 0.60 and the problem was happening on ios and android. 
the only solution that worked for me was running 
`react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` 
Then, when the error appears, run
`npm install` (Keep the bundler and the simulator open)
then run `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and i resolved it by making changes in **AppDelegate.m** file. I changed

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

to

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

And it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of answers above.
But the only that works for is a watchman command(I use `react-native: "0.60.4"`):

`watchman watch-del-all`

Answer (score 0):

For Ios follow the below steps,

1. rm -rf ./node_modules
2. npm install
3. react-native link
4. cd ios
5. Pod Install
6. cd..
7. react-native start
8. Build the app in XCode 1st time then you can also from VScode

Answer (score 0):

I had this screen as well, but my problem was that I had been using a proxy the night before (using Charles to monitor network requests from the RN env).

Once I shut off the proxy the app built/ran with no problems in my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you have a command set to be executed at startup in a terminal session (.bashrc/.bash_profile) that awaits for an input (in my case, the passphrase for an SSH Key with `ssh-add`), then you'll notice it actually prevents the opened Terminal to start the Metro server!

Try disabling that command at startup (or at least in the Terminal opened by React Native). It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem while staying in a home where I could only use their "guest" Wi-Fi network. I tried setting up a proxy to intercept traffic and determine which URL it was using to connect. Unexpectedly, it turned out that the proxy itself fixed the issue.

I installed [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/) on my Mac and followed the [iOS setup instructions](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-device) to proxy my iOS traffic through my computer. However, when setting up the proxy on my iPhone, I used my computer's hostname (in my case, tobias-m1-max.local) as the proxy address, instead of my IP address.

I then used the `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` environment variable so that my iPhone would use my computer's hostname instead of IP address to connect to the packager server. In my case with Expo, the command was `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=tobias-m1-max.local expo start --dev-client`.

Expo then generates a QR code for me to scan which opens my development app and uses `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` to connect to the packager server via the proxy, and I can work again!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue with my metro.config.js file. With some help from GPT-4 I set it to the following value:

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['db', 'mp3', 'ttf', 'png', 'jpg', 'otf', 'obj', 'bin', 'txt', 'mtl', 'JPG', 'vrx', 'hdr', 'gltf', 'glb', 'bmp', 'gif', 'ico', 'tif', 'tga', 'mov', 'cur'],
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'mjs', 'js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'svg']
  }
};
```

And that fixed it.

I am too lazy to figure out exactly what about my old file was causing the issue, but here was the metro.config.js that was causing the error:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    ...defaultConfig.transformer,
    // Add your custom configurations here.
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
    // Add other custom configurations here.
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR EXPO - Clearing Cache worked for me**

For anyone running into this problem with Expo, clearing cache worked for me

```
expo r -c
```

This solves the issue most of the times, but I ran into some binary related issues. To resolve this I ran

```
npx expo prebuild
```

and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above, but it didn't work until I unchecked "For install builds only" like the screenshot below.

note: make sure the metro bundler is working.

[image: nchecked "For install builds only"]

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, but if you have 2 Wi-Fi networks, then try to use the other one. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used Xcode, and this is what helped me. I changed `Build Configuration` from `Debug` to `Release`.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem *could* be that the device can't connect to your Mac. There can be many reasons for this and some of the other answers are alluding to this (turn off VPNs, make sure you are one the same internet etc)

In my case it was important that:

1. The common internet doesnt block port 8081. Our work wifi blocks this so we use a personal hotspot and connect both devices to this.
2. That `node` accepts incoming connections. In my case I had pressed "No" when asked about accepting incoming connections a long time a go. You can change this in the firewall settings (System Settings -> Network -> Firewall)

Again the device needs to be able to reach the computer. In my case it logged in XCode that a request to "my-computers-ip:8081/status" timed out. This is the status page for the metro bundler.

Answer (score -1):

Closing the currently running `React Packager` terminal window, and then re-running your iOS project from Xcode should work.

Answer (score -1):

**Use the command**

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/release/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios/release/main.jsbundle
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are running IOS simulator make sure need to run this command

react-native run-android 
or 
npm run-android

once you running above command metro bundler will start , then run react-nagtive run-ios it will work .

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you forgot this step

```
cd ios && pod install
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this question has many answers But these are not helped me. Below solution that helped me to resolve the error.

You have to go into your settings and allow this particular app.

1. Open system preferences.
2. Click 'security & privacy".
3. Bottom right-click " Click the lock to make changes".
4. Enter password.
5. Under the general tab where it says ' app store and identified developers' you should see your blocked app.
6. Final step: click "open anyway"

Source [“launchPackager.command” cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516286/launchpackager-command-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-dev)