# No Bundle URL Found - React Native Getting Started

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, config

I am following the steps at [React Native Getting Started](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) and I am unable to get the application running. When I run `cd /Users/brandonsmac/SysDevMobileApps/ReactNative/AwesomeApp" && npx react-native run-ios`

It will say successfully built, but when I got to view the screen it says "Bundle URL Missing"

I notice there is the following post that I tried [react-native No bundle URL present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951790/react-native-no-bundle-url-present) and I still get the error.

Also, I can show what happens when I run it with the expo but that fails as well.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 11):

The answer I found here worked.
https://onexlab-io.medium.com/no-bundle-url-present-fixed-ca2688a80f66

### Step 1:

- Open the package.json file and add the following line

  `"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='iOS'"`
- Now your file looks like this following screenshot

[image: [Step 1][]

### Step 2:

- Run following command. It will generate main.jsbundle file

  yarn build:ios
  or
  npm run build:ios

### Step 3:

- Open iOS project in Xcode show as following screenshot

[image: Step 3 Part 1]

- `Select -> Target → Build Phases` under **Copy Bundle Resources** click
  on the **plus button** as following screenshot.

[image: Step 3 Part 2]

- It will show you the prompt as shown below. Then select the file
  **main.jsbundle** and click on the **Add button**

[image: Step 3 Part 3]

### Step 4:

Try to re-run your app

```
npx react-native run-ios
or
react-native run-ios
```

### Step 5:

TA DA!!
[image: Step 5 Complete]

Comment: A variation of this answer worked for me. After it ran I noticed i was not able to debug remotely, it was complaning about localhost:8081, so I checked my HOSTS file and saw that at some point I removed the _127.0.0.1_ localhost reference. After I put it back, I was able to debug again remotely.

Comment: I have tried this solution but get the error, error opening bundle private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxx.xxx.xxx/myappnative.app/main.jsbundle&inlineSourceMap=true - any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

What work for me is to

1. Click on the App Target
2. Look for Bundle React Native code and images
3. Uncheck run script for install builds only
4. Uncheck run script based on dependency analysis.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

For me it was fixed by unchecking `run script only when installing` here:

Targets -> Build Phases -> Bundle React Native code and images

[image: Bundle React Native code and images]