# No bundle URL present (react native)

Tags: react-native

Just installed react native and trying to get Hello World up and running. Been receiving this error for the last few hours:

```
 "No bundle URL present.Make sure you're running a packager server
 or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle."
```

I've referred to this: [What means of no bundle URL present in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610070/what-means-of-no-bundle-url-present-in-react-native) and other similar questions, and tried everything: using my ip addresse, different combos of react-native run-iso and npm install while running and not running, tried deleting builds, cleaning project, restarting Xcode, simulator multiple times,  tried react-native-upgrade, edited into.plist to allow arbitrary loads, manually setting the path to my index.ios.js, everything, and nothing works.

I noticed many ran into this issue when trying to build on their device. i'm not trying to do anything fancy, just get 'hello world' up and running.

Any other solutions I am not aware of?

Comment: after reading your question i don't know in which page are you in however the simplest way might have been to run the server by react-native start command...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What means of no bundle URL present in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610070/what-means-of-no-bundle-url-present-in-react-native)

Answer (score 24):

cd into `YOUR_PROJECT/ios` and `rm -r build`, then run again `react-native run-ios`

Comment: Then we need to move to the project and use the react-native run-ios command. 
Thanks it worked for me.

Comment: The build dir doesn't exist for me - I guess it is cleaned up ???  I am just using the `expo` solution to run on my actual iPhone device (and not simulator) as per https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: I also don't have the build dir @HankCa, were you able to find the solution?

Comment: No, I paused work in React Native.  I will start up again soon.  First I'd read https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react-native/ (I've no affiliation except I like the newline.io books and business model). They've also an article - https://www.newline.co/@kchan/building-macos-applications-with-react-native-for-macos--7fd38809 and I'm not sure if that is from the book.  Heaps of other resources I'd follow including https://blog.crowdbotics.com/the-state-of-react-native-for-windows-macos-2021/.  The toughest part of this tech is a need to have understanding of the native platform aswell as React.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue, my problem was with `info.plist` I just 
config it as the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

from this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471978/1627358

And then add Bash config file .bashrc with this command:

```
echo "alias rni=\"kill \$(lsof -t -i:8081); rm -rf ios/build/; react-native run-ios\"" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc
```

Then run `rni`

from this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44080527/1627358](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471978/1627358)

And it works fine with me.

Answer (score 12):

run the following code:

```
killall -9 node
rm -rf ios/build
react-native run-ios
```

it will open launchpackager.command and the application will install on the ios simulator

Answer (score 9):

The solution that worked for me.

You need to run:

```
yarn start
```

And at the same time (in a different terminal window):

```
yarn run:ios
```

Comment: I see other videos where it runs all by clicking RUN on XCODE, why I have to start the bundler separately?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you are using `nvm` and multiple versions of node installed, here is the solution:

1. Say that you run `npm install -g react-native-cli` in `node v6.9.5`.
2. Now make `node v6.9.5` as default by running `nvm alias default 6.9.5`
3. Now run `react-native run-ios`

The problem is, you have multiple versions of node installed via `nvm` and to install `react-native-cli` you have switched or installed latest version of node, which is not marked as default node to point in `nvm` yet. When you run `react-native run-ios` this opens up another new terminal window in which default `nvm` is not pointed to the node version where you have installed `react-native-cli`. Just follow the above setup, I hope that should help.

Answered the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267703/1292050

Comment: This solved mine because a diff node version was default, and the run-ios command pops a new terminal window which defaulted to a super old node version. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue after I run the following commands to clean the project to see the changes which were invisible because of the cache and so on:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-* or npm start -- -- reset-cache
rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*
```

The reason for the issue was in the comment in dom-structure which didn't let the application run on the device. **So, check the comments too ;)**

Answer (score 3):

faced similar issue while running in real device app was getting crash after uploading to testflight upload and install folks this issue is killer

saved by this link
https://onexlab-io.medium.com/no-bundle-url-present-fixed-ca2688a80f66

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Instead of just linking to a webpage which answers the question, please take your time to provide an answer here and support it with a citation to the linked article.

Answer (score 2):

The below solved the same problem i had

brew update

brew reinstall watchman

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by running `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios` command on the app's root terminal.

If a file called *main.jsbundle* is created inside your *ios* folder, then rebuild the app.
Else, it is likely that you got some output like

```
info Writing bundle output to:, ios/main.jsbundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 61 asset files
warn Assets destination folder is not set, skipping...
```

If so go to
*XCode >>* {Your App} *>>* {Your App Target} *>> Build Phases >> Bundle React Native code and images*
and replace the `node` in `export NODE_BINARY=node` with the output of `which node` command executed on a different terminal.

[image: Update RN Bundle node path]

Then re-run `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios` and generate the *main.jsbundle* file.

Then add the file to your app by right clicking *XCode >>* {Your App} and selecting the **Add files to "**{Your App Name}**"** option. Then select the newly created *main.jsbundle* file. Check if the file is added to
*XCode >>* {Your App} *>>* {Your App Target} *Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources*

If the file is there, rebuild the app.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me.

```
> sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

add

```
 # Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

then

```
> sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

the reason is I change  `hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue happen to me not too long ago. It appears that if you renamed the project to something else and the project folder itself was renamed, you need to make sure you replace all instances of the old name with the new name and do not forget to change file names of your .xcscheme in ProjectName > ios > ProjectName.xcodeproj > xcshareddata > xcschemes. I also had to remove the build directory. Hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue when I tried to sync my files to iCloud Drive. I have no idea what causes this, but as soon as I turn off my iCloud Drive and reinstall brew and Node, it started to work again. I can only think that when I turned on iCloud Drive, I might have ended up having two different Node versions or any other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, your best first step is to scroll through the log text that outputs in the terminal window where you fired off "npx react-native run-ios" and search for the word like "error" or "failed".  This will point you toward something more specific than the general "No bundle URL present" error.

For example, you might see something like "**BUILD FAILED** The following build commands failed: ProcessInfoPlistFile".  In this example, I'd then know to go check on my Info.plist.  You might see something different, but the debug methodology would still be the same.

If you are trying to run iOS, another idea is to build your app with Xcode itself by opening <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>.xcworkspace with Xcode, then review its error messages.

Similarly, if you are trying to run Android, then try running with Android Studio and review its error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Edit **/etc/hosts**
`127.0.0.1  localhost` 
this is work for me !!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: when i did some changes on /etc/hosts i've got this error. this solution fix my problem  too +1

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers are given, but one thing you should surely be taking care of while facing this issue is to

> ***make sure that your Metro server is running.***

Answer (score 0):

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

Try This, clear project, and run in xCode.

Comment: Hey, it's not clear if the needed is to run the command, clear project, run in Xcode or clear project then run the provided command in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

This relates to the answers from @Daria Kozlova and @Daniel Twork

I needed to have the server running in another tab, i.e. `yarn start`

But what I hadn't noticed is that the server had crashed with an error like:

```
jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/anentropic/Documents/Dev/Work/myproject/mobile-app: Operation not permitted. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.

...

  watchmanResponse: {
    error: 'std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/anentropic/Documents/Dev/Work/myproject/mobile-app: Operation not permitted',
    version: '2022.09.12.00'
  }
```

The fix for that can be found here:
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/977#issuecomment-1189903929

i.e. run:

```bash
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
```

and then `yarn start` again

`react-native run-ios` works now

Answer (score 0):

just try,

- npm start
- npm react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

In the package.json add the following in the script section,

```
"bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
```

The quotes around file name and platform value is a must.

In the pipeline execute

```
yarn bundle:ios
```

before archiving. That's it, updated main.jsbundle will get added to the package. If your project path is different then slight change in path might be required.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above, but it didn't work until I unchecked "For install builds only" like the screenshot below.

note: make sure the metro bundler is working.

[image: uncheck "For install builds only"]

Comment: This is a secret swiss-knife. It just work especially when you use physical device not simulator

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

If I run Metro before building the project from xcode, it works fine and the issue disappears.

But if try to build the project from xcode without Metro running the error appears again.

Answer (score -2):

There must be built issues in your app. Try building with Xcode or terminal