# Make Sure You're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle. (error showing running already build project)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am running React Native project using npx react-native run-ios in terminal but its showing the following error:

```
Make sure you're running a packager server or have
included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.

RCTFatal 
28—[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invok e 
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF 
_CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_Q UEUE 
_CFRunLoopRun 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific 
GSEventRunModal 
—[UlApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain 
main 
start
```

Solutions I have already tried

- Changing port
- Downgrading node module
- Downgrading both React Native and project
- Upgrading Firebase to the latest version and reinstalling it
- Killing port if there is any script running

I have tried almost everything online and am looking for a solution.

Comment: So [none of these answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=RCTFatal+RCTCxxBridge+handleError+site:stackoverflow.com) helped?

Comment: Did you not miss the title of the error, like "No bundle URL present" - then you may have a dupe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949607/no-bundle-url-present-react-native)

Comment: @mplungjan i have tried this but it did not resolve my issue

Comment: open dev tools (ctrl + m for ios simulator or shake device if its not simulator), then there in settings some where you can edit ip address, add your computers local ip with port,

Answer (score 0):

Adding this:

```
"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
```

to my package.json "scripts" worked form me.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, I faced this issue with "react-native": "0.70.6". I renamed my "index.tsx" file to "index.js" file now it's ok.

and also in app level build.gradle file:

```java
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,    //clean and rebuild if changing
    entryFile: "index.js", // "index.tsx",
]
```