# From Xcode Only : "No bundle URL present Make sure you’re running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

#### Description

On Xcode 15 (MacOS Sonoma) I have the following error when building my project : *Build success* but **No bundle URL present Make sure you’re running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file**

However, when I build it from command line, everything works.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-native run-ios --port=8082 --simulator='iPhone 15 Pro' && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start
```

What's missing on Xcode? How to solve that?

#### React Native Version

0.63.3

#### Output of `npx react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 14.0
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 47.94 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.17.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.6.7 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.09.04.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.0, iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, tvOS 17.0, watchOS 10.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 15.0/15A240d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
    Python: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

#### Steps to reproduce

Build from Xcode (Debug or Release)

#### Snack, screenshot, or link to a repository

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

In the Build Phases section of Xcode, find the Bundle React Native Code and Images section and add this at the start

```
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/bin" ] && [ -x "/opt/homebrew/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
fi
```

(assuming your homebrew installation hasn't been installed somewhere non standard)

Comment: Hi! Just add it, but same result : "Build success with error `Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.`"

Comment: The above works for me whenever I have this issue. However React Native has a history of not every solution that works for one person works for another, there's several similar past question, search for some and try some of the things to try they suggest, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949607/no-bundle-url-present-react-native

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75602510/387912 (thanks to [Manil Malla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19476877/manil-malla))

1. I had to manually create the bundle.

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

2. Add the `main.jsbundle` to **"Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources"**
   [image]

In fact, this file was missing.

3 questions remains.

- Why it has missing?
- How to do that automatically?
- **IMPORTANT (with that solution, local images (logo, icon) doesn't work anymore...)**

Comment: check this out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18472#issuecomment-408054100

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem last month in my old React Native projects. To solve this problem you just have to follow two steps the steps are below

**Step 1**  Fire this command in your root project

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios
```

**Step 2**  You have created main.jsbundle using above command add main.jsbundle to the to "Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources"[image]

[Check this out](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18472#issuecomment-408330186)

Answer (score 0):

This is how resolve this issue

```js
 "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
```

1. Just run the script in your project terminal. It will generate main.jsbundle in the ios directory
2. Open your project with xcode and navigate to **Build Phase --> Copy Bundle Resource** and then import the main.jsbundle by clicking the **+** button below
   [image]

[image]

**NOTE:** There is possibility you might not see it in the list of items by default to import. If that is the case click the **Add other** navigate through you project and add the **main.jsbundle** file

Then after that rebuild your app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me :
Xcode > your project > choose target as your project > build phases

now check the value given to data **NODE_BINARY** which is under **Bundle React Native code and images**. if it is too dependent on your locale this will cause errors.

example : NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

error : NODE_BINARY=/opt/homebrew/bin/node