# “launchPackager.command” cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, runtime-error, macos-catalina

```
macOS Catalina 10.15
```

> app not run in ios:- show me this warning.

[image]

Answer (score 29):

You have to go into your settings and allow this particular app.

1. Open system preferences
2. Click 'security & privacy"
3. Bottom right click " Click the lock to make changes"
4. Enter password
5. Under the general tab where it says ' app store and identified developers ' you should see your blocked app.
6. Final step: click "open anyway"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it works, but we have to repeat the task everytime.. It is not persistence :(

Comment: Let me know if you find a permanent solution for this