# React Native iOS No Bundle URL present but only when using a real device

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I am trying to build a project that we have previously built many times on a real device through xcode but not it throws a No Bundle URL present error the moment the app boots.

I have tried updating the app, rebooting and updating the info.plist file but nothing seems to change it.

Other apps are booting fine.

I have my info and the error below.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawzN.png)

[image: App Info]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are running correct Project. Clean you build folder and then Run .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a common issue for some. I'd suggest checking out this thread with others that had a similar issue - [What is the meaning of 'No bundle URL present' in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610070/what-is-the-meaning-of-no-bundle-url-present-in-react-native)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31742864)