# Getting "No bundle URL present error" on Mac m1 in react-native v0.68.0

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I have been using react native 0.68 version on my new mac m1 pro chip.
My code is working on android but on iOS i am getting "no bundle URL present error".
If i manually create main.jsbundle file and then run it, then the app is working fine but, for that every-time i need to create the bundle file if i am updating my code.

So, any one have face this kind of issue?

[image: NoBundleURLError]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of 'No bundle URL present' in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610070/what-is-the-meaning-of-no-bundle-url-present-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by doing this:

Open host file `sudo vi /private/etc/hosts`
Add three line if it's not exist

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 localhost
::1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window
cd into YOUR_PROJECT/ios
Remove the build folder with

```
rm -r build
```

Run

```
react-native run-ios
```

again.

Alternatively, you could open Finder, navigate to YOUR_PROJECT/ios and delete the build folder.

Then run react-native run-ios again.

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Are you still getting this error?

Comment: yes, i have tried many ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
--> open ios file project with xcode
--> in project bundle delete main.jsbundle file
--> add new empty file by main.jsbundle name
-->Run command: react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
--> now react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Not working for me.